# What are this tunic and badge?

Tags: 19th-century, identification

Can anyone identify this tunic and badge from the mid 1800’s.  Similar to a [Doggett Coat and Badge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doggett%27s_Coat_and_Badge) but isn’t. I assume it relates to London.

The tunic and badge is shown in the picture and what appears to be the Thames and St Paul’s through the window.

[image]

Comment: What makes you sure it's not Doggett's Coat and Badge?

Comment: @SteveBird [Difficult for me to make it out](https://earth.app.goo.gl/WYwFYX) because the Photosphere is blurry but it looks different.  Also, the Wikipedia article mentions the "Horse of Hanover" and the word "Liberty" and the side view in the painting doesn't appear to have either.

Comment: Or, I could have done it the easy way and used a [Google image search](https://images.app.goo.gl/uguVMpdgQNeho2rM6).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right it's not a Doggets Coat and Badge, but, from Wikipedia:

> The winner's prize is a traditional watermen's red coat with a silver badge added.

I would guess that what we have here is a "traditional watermens's red coat", and so presumably this is an eighteenth/nineteenth century member of the Company, with a different badge on the arm. The badge looks like a version of the Company's crest - see the one on the top of the page [here](https://watermenscompany.com/) with the curved fish as a supporter and a crest on top.

(Note that as well as the scene clearly being of London as seen by St Paul's and the bridge, the river has two or three boats shown)

Comment: The haircut and hat look 19th century.

Comment: It seems to me the trophy cup on the table in the painting might imply some relationship to an *event* of some sort, not just a traditional jacket of a member of one of the Livery Companies.